# Parallel task lags Form Load

Tags: winforms, parallel.foreach

I am running two long parallel tasks before Form_Load using

```
private void task1()
{
    //Long task
}
private void task2()
{
    //Long task
}
Task tsk=new Task(task1);
Task tsk2=new Task(task2); 
Parallel.ForEach(new [] {tsk, tsk2},item=>item.Start());.
```

When the form opens after the tasks get completed,the form hangs when minimised by clicking the application button in taskbar , for 30 seconds, and then becomes active. Is there a way to overcome this?
Thanks

**Edited To Add:**

```
private static bool modalDisposed=false;
private ModalLoad ml = new ModalLoad();
private void Form_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    ml.Show(this);
    Task tsk=new Task(task1);
    Task tsk2=new Task(task2); 
    Parallel.ForEach(new [] {tsk, tsk2},item=>item.Start());.
}
private void task1()
{
    //long task
    modalDisposed=true;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    Application.OpenForms["ModalLoad"].Dispose();
}
private void task2()
{
    while(!modalDisposed)
    {
        ml.updateLabel();
    }
}
```

In the modal form, I update the label

```
private static int ui=0;
public void updateLabel()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lblUI.Text=ui+"";
        ui++;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.  What happens **inside** your tasks, though?  Are you attempting to update the UI perhaps?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sorry for the delay, I have edited my question, thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of a second Task and a `while` loop, add a **Timer** to your Form and simply increment your counter from the Tick() event.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Hi, I tried using a timer, but the tick event is raised only after the task1 gets completed. :(

Comment: Then you either haven't shown us your complete Task1 code, or you still have code somewhere else that is preventing your UI from processing messages (like your while loop that is indirectly calling `Invoke()` at high speed).